# Override email address in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, subscriber

In marketing cloud, if i have a sendable data extension that relates to all subscribers by subscriber key, and the data extension also contains an email address field:

On sending, if the subscriber already exists, the email address used for sending is the one in the all subscribers and the one in the sendable data extension is not used.

Is there any way to alter this behavior? to make marketing cloud use the email address in the sendable data extension no matter is that is different from the email address in the all subscribers.

Comment: how are you sending the email that you are experiencing the issue? User Initiated, trigger email, send wizard, journey builder?  I personally have never experienced this before, so any further details into the issue you can provide the better we can assist.

Comment: User initiated send. It's out of the box behavior to send the email to the subscriber's email address in all subcribers.

Comment: But if you assign the sending relationship for the new DE, you should be able to match the email addresses.  E.g. EmailAddress field in DE matches Email Address field in Subscribers.  This way it will send to email addresses in DE, not based off Subscriber ID or Subscriber Key values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating All Subscribers from Data Extension](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/234788/updating-all-subscribers-from-data-extension)

Comment: To @Gortonington, thanks for your reply. But I actually need to use the subscriber attributes that relates to my subscriber key but just with another email address. Your solution would involve auto creating new subscribers when the email addresses are not found. Thanks also Jackson-chen, but that involves a whole bulk recurrent process to update all subs. 
To all: There is another solution more straightforward: theres a business rule that just needs to be activated to achieve this behavior.