# Should subsequent opt-outs and bounces be handled manually?

Tags: marketing-cloud, bounce-management

Using a sendable data extension containing an `Id` column connected to `Subscriber Key`, we are sending two emails to the recipients inside the data extension. If we encounter opt-outs and bounces during the first send, does SFMC remove them automatically or should they be handled manually using e.g. using excluded lists in the *User-initiated Send*?

I'm wondering if there's an official documentation about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good description of how bounce management is handled by SFMC in [this help article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_bounce_mail_management.htm&type=5). Especially the decision tree provides an easy overview when a recipient is excluded from email sends:

[image: Bounce mail management in Salesforce Marketing Cloud]

When it comes to opt-outs, it depends on how you handle them. If someone opts out "programatically" (i.e. by list-unsubscribe header), this is registered on All Subscribers and this person will [no longer receive your emails](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_unsubscribes.htm&type=5). 
If you are using a custom preference center, this behaviour will still be valid, however your regular opt-out link will probably update a consent record in a data extension, and your segmentation should exclude this person from future sends.

Comment: Ok, we use Salesforce own opt-out list so their opt-out info should be applied on the All Subscriber list (even though we are using Data Extensions). As far as I see in your detailed diagram, it should be Salesforce who takes care of bounces as well. In that case, I don't think we need to manually apply exclusion lists or remove the optput from our SQL query activities in Automation Studio. Have I understood you correctly?

Comment: Correct - once subscriber status changes to Undeliverable, no more emails should be sent. You should put a solution in place, which changes the status to Active when subscriber updates the email address. The new one will most probably not bounce.

Comment: OK, isn't this done by default? Where should I apply this solution?

Comment: Create an automation, which checks the email address in your data extension against the email address in All Subscribers. If the email addresses differ, overwrite the email address in all subscribers with the one from the data extension, and update the subscriber status to Active. This is described a.o. here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/234788/updating-all-subscribers-from-data-extension

Comment: Thank you so much! Will do so.